# How to use selectedOption in react-select

Tags: reactjs, onclick, onchange, react-select

I use react-select and I'm new.I have a component called Example that executes the handleChange method correctly

```
const colourOptions = [
  { value: '1', label: '1', color: '#00B8D9' },
  { value: '2', label: '2', color: '#0052CC' },
  { value: '3', label: '3', color: '#5243AA' },
];

class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: null,
  }

  handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    console.log(selectedOption)
  }

  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    return (
        <Select
          value={selectedOption}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          options={colourOptions}
        />
    );
  }
}

export default Example;
```

In another file we have a button

```
export default function UserProfile() {
  return (
    <div>

      <Example1/>
      <Example2/>
      <Example3/>

      <Button type="Submit">Search</Button>

    </div>
  );
}
```

How can I display the value of selectedOption by clicking on the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to maintain the selectedOption and the handleChange in the parent(UserProfile) and pass them down to the child(Example).

**UserProfile Component**

```js
export default function UserProfile() {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState({});

  const handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    setSelectedOption(selectedOption)
    console.log(selectedOption)
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(selectedOption);      
  };

  return (
    <div>

      <Example onHandleChange={handleChange} selectedOption={selectedOption}/>

      <Button onClick={handleClick} type="Submit">Search</Button>

    </div>
  );
}
```

**Example Component**

```js
class Example extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { selectedOption, onHandleChange } = this.props;

    return (
        <Select
          value={selectedOption}
          onChange={onHandleChange}
          options={colourOptions}
        />
    );
  }
}

export default Example;
```